# Make to form search in CodeIgniter using two fields

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, web

Hi I'm newbie and I want make a form to search in CodeIgniter using two fields but I am confused in controller & models
so help me please ..

```
    <input id="srchFld" class="srchTxt" name="keyword" type="text" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata("keyword"); ?>" />
      <select class="srchTxt" name="kategori">
        <option>All</option>
          <?php
        foreach ($kat as $kategori){
            $id = $kategori['id'];
            $nama_kategori = $kategori['nama_kategori'];
            $created_at = $kategori['created_at'];

    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $id;  ?>"><?php echo $nama_kategori;  ?></option>

         <?php } ?>
    </select> 

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I am confused in controller & models..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you need to implement something like this:

```
function search(){
  $filters['keyword'] = $this->input->post('keyword', TRUE);
  $filters['kategori'] = $this->input->post('kategori', TRUE);

  // pass this params to the model
  $data = $this->yourmodel->search($filters);

  // pass search results to the view
  $this->load->view('view_file', $data);
}
```

in your model

```
function search($filters){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field LIKE ? AND other_field = ?"; 
  return $this->db->query($sql, array($filters['keyword'], $filters['kategori']))->result_array();
}
```

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Hi, first of all you can add comment instead of editing original answer, second, maybe that error appears because there is no matches for the search term and category you entered, try another one.